# How to animate stack panel when toggle button or button is clicked to change visibility from hidden to visible?

Tags: wpf

I want to make some animations for stack Panel like sliding right side.Whenever button is clicked it should animate from hidden to visible. How can i do that?

```
      <ToggleButton Margin="40,0,0,0" Name="shw" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Height="25" Width="85" Background="White">
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" Text="Select Columns" Padding="0,0,2,0"/>
                </ToggleButton>
                <StackPanel  Margin="40" Name="pnlLeftMenu" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <StackPanel.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked,ElementName=shw}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </StackPanel.Style>
                    <Border BorderBrush="#FF16A3F7" BorderThickness="2" Width="150" Height="Auto" Background="White" >
                        <ListBox SelectionMode="Multiple" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ItemsSource="{Binding CustomList}"  VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="White">
                            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                                <CheckBox Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsSelected}" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="12" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="10,0"/>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        </ListBox>
                    </Border>
                </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

Use `Checked` and `UnChecked` Routed Events of Toggle button with Event Trigger:

```
 <ToggleButton x:Name="ProductToggleButton" Content="Toggle" Height="20" Width="60" Panel.ZIndex="10" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <ToggleButton.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Checked">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard >
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="pnlLeftMenu" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Unchecked">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="pnlLeftMenu" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </ToggleButton.Triggers>
    </ToggleButton>

    <StackPanel Background="Yellow" Margin="40" Name="pnlLeftMenu" Opacity="0" Orientation="Vertical" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Border BorderBrush="#FF16A3F7" BorderThickness="2" Width="150" Height="Auto" Background="White" >
            <ListBox SelectionMode="Multiple" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ItemsSource="{Binding CustomList}"  VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="White">
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                    <CheckBox Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsSelected}" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="12" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="10,0"/>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ListBox>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
```

**Result:**

[image: Result]